# Alignment at equals signs in two columns of an array environment

Tags: arrays

I would like to make a table of two columns of the squares of all the digits. With the following code, there is no proper spacing between the equals sign and the numbers in the first column, and the equals sign is not typeset in the second column.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$
\begin{array}{r@{${}={}$}lc@{\qquad\qquad}cr@{${}={}$}l}
0^2&0, & 5^2&25, \\
1^2&1, & 6^2&36, \\
2^2&4, & 7^2&49, \\
3^2&9, & 8^2&64, \\
4^2&16, & 9^2&81.
\end{array}
$$

\end{document}
```

I would appreciate tips on how to do this only using the array environment.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a fifth column in between the two groups. In my opinion, it's unnecessary. Here is a simpler code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{r@{{}²={}}l!{\qquad}r@{{}²={}}l}
0&0, & 5&25, \\
1&1, & 6&36, \\
2&4, & 7&49, \\
3&9, & 8&64, \\
4&16, &9&81.
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see that you have typeset a $2$ in the exponent position within the `@{}` alignment marker. Shouldn't you have "`^2`"?

Comment: Why is there an exclamation mark? Why can't I get more space between the columns by adding another `\qquad` or `\qquad\quad`?

Comment: @user74973 please read the manual for the `array` package, all you ask for is explained there.

Comment: @user74973: `!{\quad}` *adds*  1 em to the normal intercolumn space which makes a totlal of 1em+10pt, whereas `@{\quad}` *replaces* the intercolumn space with a space of 1 em.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask TeX to do the computations itself in whatever radix you like (up to 36).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,array,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\digitsquares}{sO{c}m}
 {% #1 * option for the header, #2 = alignment, #3 = radix
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \multicolumn{6}{c}{\mbox{Base ~ $#3$}} \\ \midrule }
   }
   {
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  \int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { \int_div_round:nn { #3 } { 2 } - 1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
     {
      \int_to_Base:nn { ##1 } { #3 } ^2 & = & \int_to_Base:nn { (##1)*(##1) } { #3 } &
      \int_compare:nT { ##1 + \int_div_round:nn { #3 } { 2 } < #3 }
       {
        \int_to_Base:nn { ##1 + \int_div_round:nn { #3 } { 2 } } { #3 }^2 & = &
        \int_to_Base:nn
         {
          (##1 + \int_div_round:nn { #3 } { 2 })*
          (##1 + \int_div_round:nn { #3 } { 2 })
         } { #3 }
        \exp_not:N \\
       }
     }
   }
  \begin{array}[#2]{@{} r @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} l @{\qquad} r @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} l @{}}
  \l_tmpa_tl
  \end{array}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\digitsquares*[t]{10} \qquad \digitsquares*[t]{7}
\]
\[
\digitsquares{16}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `*` means that we want the header; the optional argument is for passing the alignment option to `array`. The mandatory argument is the radix.

The `array` preamble consists of two sets

```
r @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} l
```

that is: right aligned column, no space, a centered column with `{}` on either side of the item (it will be the `=` sign), left aligned column; in between a `\qquad` separation. The leading and trailing `@{}` nullify the padding on either side of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a platform that apparently does not allow all the options for an array environment. It may only allow `l`, `r`, `c`, and `@{\qquad}`. I have modified my code so that it gives me exactly what I want.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{array}{r@{}l @{\qquad\qquad} r@{}l}
0^2 &{}={} 0, & 5^2 &{}={} 25, \\
1^2 &{}={} 1, & 6^2 &{}={} 36, \\
2^2 &{}={} 4, & 7^2 &{}={} 49, \\
3^2 &{}={} 9, & 8^2 &{}={} 64, \\
4^2 &{}={} 16, & 9^2 &{}={} 81.
\end{array}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bernard  I have posted an answer in order to show a modification of my code.  I didn't want to edit the original post because it would help others using a typical LaTeX editor. I am using an online editor which has limited features. I would appreciate your help on editing my code in "my answer."

Comment: Can't you load the `array` package? It is very basic.

Comment: No, the online platform does not allow the user to upload any packages.

Comment: But maybe it *is* installed on the platform? After all, you can load amsmath. Why not array?

Comment: I only included the preamble so that the code can be compiled by someone trying to help me. On this online platform, I only encode what I want to have printed.

Comment: `array` doesn't print whatever by itself   – it only yields tools for tabulars and arrays.

Comment: @Bernard I edited the code in "my answer." It gives me the array that I had wanted.

Comment: Fine! Actually, the difference with my code is that you have more code to type – I delegated part of the typing to the table preamble via `>{...}`.